# Validation Layer

Tags: c#-4.0

I saw this reply in Stackoverflow for best practice validation:

```
[Flags]
public enum ValidationError {
  None = 0,
  SomeError = 1,
  OtherError = 2,
  ThirdError = 4
  }
```

//...and in the calling code, simply:

ValidationError errCode = employee.Validate();
   if(errCode != ValidationError.None) {
    // Do something
    }

It looks good, except I need to return the actual error message (friendly error message)

Any input to improve the above code?

Answer (score 0):

You could always store the error messages in an array.